# Vim - How to highlight a part of a pattern

Tags: c#, vim, syntax-highlighting

I want to highlight an object in Vim C#.

I do the following in cs.vim:

```
syn match csObject  "[A-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*\.[A-Z]"
```

And highlight it in my color theme

```
hi csObject     guifg=#ff0000
```

However it paints also the . and the first letter from the next "word".

[image]

How to highlight only the match before the dot?

**EDIT** 
Thanks to the @romainl answer I found out that `\zs` sets the start of a match and `\za` sets the end of a match.

That's allowed me to make the match properly:

```
syn match csObject         "[ \t\(\!]\zs[A-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]\{-}\ze\.[A-Z]"
```

Comment: This belongs on http://vi.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=116

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need one tiny modification to your regular expression to solve your issue.

Your pattern actually covers `Application`, the `.`, and the following uppercase letter. What you should do is use `\ze` to mark the end of the "useful" part of your pattern:

```
syn match csObject "[A-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*\ze\.[A-Z]"
```

Also, I would use `\{-}` instead of the too greedy `*`.

Comment: Excellent. My theme is as near as possible to the VisualStudio: http://s28.postimg.org/uvblzudvx/screenshot_1196.png

Comment: Good job. Are you going to release it?